# React Material UI Table Sort

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I have it so that the Name column is sorted by default (ASC) - and I just need to work out the onclick so it changes this sort order when clicked.

```
function descendingComparator(a,b, orderBy) {
    console.log('a',a)
    console.log('b',b)
    console.log('orderBy',orderBy)
    if(b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]){
      console.log('-1')
      return -1;
    }
    if(b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]){
      console.log('1')
      return 1;
    }
    console.log('0')
    return 0;
  }
  
  function getComparator(order, orderBy){
    return order === "desc"
      ? (a,b) => descendingComparator(a,b, orderBy)
      : (a,b) => -descendingComparator(a,b, orderBy)
  }
  
  const sortedRowInformation = (rowArray, comparator) => {
    const stabilizedRowArray = rowArray.map((el, index) => [el, index])
    stabilizedRowArray.sort((a,b) =>{
      const order = comparator(a[0], b[0])
      if(order !==0) return order;
      return a[1] - b[1];
  })
  return stabilizedRowArray.map((el) => el[0])
  }
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0)
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5)
  const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(0)
  const [order, setOrder] = useState()
  const [orderBy, setorderBy] = useState()
  const [orderDirection, setorderDirection] = useState("asc")
  const [valueToOrderBy, setvalueToOrderBy] = useState("Name")
```

And my Table:

```
<TableCell align = "left" key = "system">
             <TableSortLabel
               active={valueToOrderBy === "Name"}
               direction={valueToOrderBy === "Name" ? orderDirection: 'asc'}
               onClick={createSortHandle("Name")}
             >
               NAME
             </TableSortLabel>
           </TableCell>
<TableBody>
      {
           sortedRowInformation(listItemFood, getComparator(orderDirection, valueToOrderBy))
           .map((item, index1) => (
          <TableRow hover key={item.id} id={item.id}>
          <TableCell>{item.Category}</TableCell>
          <TableCell><a href="#updateItem" onClick={() => editItem(item)}>{item.Name}</a></TableCell>
          <TableCell>{item.Weight}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>
          <IconButton size="small" aria-label="edit" onClick={() => editItem(item)}><a href="#updateItem"><EditOutlinedIcon /></a></IconButton><IconButton size="small" aria-label="delete" onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}><DeleteIcon /></IconButton>
          </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
      ))}
      </TableBody>
```

What is the function I need to attach to onClick={createSortHandle("Name")} in order for it to change direction when clicked?

Comment: Can you provide your complete code, then it's much easier to tackle the issue ?

Comment: Added in the TableBody as well - does that help?

Comment: Hope you can provide the complete code or code-sandbox in order to re-create the issue you're facing. With few code-snippets cannot really get a complete idea on it. I just put an answer please check whether you can modify your implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a function `createSortHandle` which returns a callback inside `TableHead` component as follows.

`onRequestSort` needs to be a prop passed down from the parent to `TableHead` component.

```
function TableHead(props) {
  const { onRequestSort } = props;
  const createSortHandler = (property) => (event) => {
    onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

...
```

Inside the `Table` component, you need to define `onRequestSort` function as follows.

```
  const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === 'asc';
    setOrder(isAsc ? 'desc' : 'asc');
  };
```

Then pass it into `TableHead` component placed inside the `Table`.

```
            <TableHead
              ...
              onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
              ...
            />
```

You can refer the **Sorting and selection** example given in the following link.

https://mui.com/components/tables/